# javascript return new function this context

Tags: javascript, this, factory

I'm using the following code to retrieve some filtered private information of a module:

```
var someObject = (function (){
    var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

    function filteredNumbersInternal(criterion) {
        return numbers.filter(function (number) { return criterion(number, this) }, this);
    }

    return {
        filteredNumbers: filteredNumbersInternal
    }
});

var someInstance = new someObject();

function less(than) {
    return function (number, context) {
        return number < than;
    }
}

var smallNumbers = someInstance.filteredNumbers(new less(5));
```

This way I can define arbitrary filter-functions and pass them to the filter-method. Is there a way I can avoid the *new* keyword when I use a factory for the filter-function, e.g. is there a way to write

```
var smallNumbers = someInstance.filteredNumbers(less(5));
```

If I write the factory like this

```
function less(than) {
    return new function (number, context) {
        return number < than;
    }
}
```

it only returns and empty object.

Comment: I don't see why you need the `new` keyword at all(it doesn't really do anything if you're returning a non-`this` value from your constructor). Your code works with `(less(5))`. See http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/xAX7K/

Comment: don't use new in either place, it should work.

Comment: Awesome. How dumb I never tried that! :-D